# Triforce ReBoot

Tags: code-golf

Seeing how hello world has backfired terribly, here is a harder one.

I love Zelda and I love ReBoot.

Create the following

[image]

**Requirements:**
It must be a window (can be ANY window even browsers and such).
The window can be of any size.
Window may not contain anything else except the picture.
Window should not close itself right away.
Triangles must be any shade of blue.
Circle must be any shade of green.
Smaller triangle must touch edges of the
No stealing images by providing links.

**Condition:** Shortest code wins.

PS: Yes ReBoot logo is slightly different but this is close enough to make it fun.

EDIT: I added another requirement. It seems like we have a lot of very genius people who enjoy finding loopholes :P I love you guys.

Comment: "Triangles must be any shade of yellow." Picture conflicts?

Comment: @Timtech I am sorry, text got underlined as orange due to misspelling and I thought orange while wanting to write blue.

Comment: Okay, at least it's fixed now. And I'm even trying to get shorter comments - too much code golfing...

Comment: Do I get bonus points if the image fills the screen, and continues to as I resize the screen? (You have to allow the circle to be an oval then)

Comment: Actually reading the requirements again, what's stop someone from just creating the image in paint, and making a program read the image? This would only be a couple of lines in python. Perhaps you should write a rule against that

Comment: And as I wrote my above comment, somebody did just that with imgur and html. (they actually just stole your image)

Comment: I made it draw it all out with GML! Only 167 characters!

Comment: @Cruncher I added the requirement. I always find it very amusing how no matter what I do there is always a loophole.

Comment: @Timtech your solution is pure genius :) I love it.

Comment: @Quillion Thanks! It's probably my best answer so far.

Comment: Wow, only 155 characters now :D

Comment: @Quillion I'm not sure if I've mentioned this to you before, but you might want to test out your questions in the current Sandbox thread in Meta before you post them. That could help shake out any unintentional loopholes first.

Comment: @Iszi ok will do from now on. Should I post all of them there first or the ones I am unsure about? This one didn't backfire right?

Comment: @Quillion Any time you feel compelled to change the rules of a challenge after it has been posted, especially in reaction to answers already submitted, it's not a good thing. I wouldn't say this one totally back-fired, but it didn't go without needing fixing, either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Mathematica <s>118 119 118 107</s> 97

Edit: Shortened to 107 chars with help from Belisarius and to 97 with alephalpha.

```
CreateDialog[Graphics@{Blue,Polygon@Outer[Plus,#,#,1]&@{{0,0},{1,1},{2,0}}, Green,
{2,1}~Circle~1}]
```

[image: triangle]

Comment: I was scared you had beat me :3 But that circle's gotta be green!

Comment: It's green now. Thanks for noting.

Comment: Augh! I've been beat! Good job :)

Comment: In 107: `p=Polygon;a={1,1};b={2,0};CreateDialog[Graphics@{Blue,p@{0a,2b,2a},White,p@{a,b+a,b},Green,{2,1}~Circle~1}]`

Comment: Nice streamlining.

Comment: `CreateDialog[Graphics@{Blue,Polygon@Outer[Plus,#,#,1]&@{{0,0},{1,1},{2,0}},Green,{2,1}~Circle~1}]`

Comment: Very clever! I tried skipping the white triangle but wasn't able to shave off so much as you.

Comment: Damnit! Here I thought I had you beat.

Comment: I got a little help from my friends.

Answer (score 7):

### Dyalog APL (<s>121</s> <s>116</s> 115)

(Edit: use triangles 8 elements wide instead of 10, to shorten code a bit)

(Edit 2: I was only ever using `M¨`, so included the `¨` in the definition of `M`)

```
M←{' ',⍵,⍺,⍨4/0}¨⋄⎕SM←↑(256M⊃,/(⊂8 0)(⊂8 32)(⊂0 16)∘.+⊂(,⍳⍴Z)/⍨≤/¨,Z←⊖Z,⌽Z←2/⍳2/8),512M⌈0 16∘+¨1 2∘×¨8+8×1 2∘○¨⍳1e4
```

Graphics? Who needs graphics?

(Also, black is the default background, you didn't say to change it)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Shell script: <s>166</s> 163 characters

```sh
f=-fill
d=-draw
convert -size 64x32 xc: $f blue $d 'polygon 32,0 0,32 64,32' $f white $d 'polygon 32,32 16,16 48,16' $f none -stroke lime $d 'circle 32,16 32,0' x:
```

Sample output:

[image: Triforce ReBoot logo]

Comment: this is more of imagemagick than shell

Comment: @mniip, right. But as ImageMagick is primarily a library. If this was a PHP script using IMagick, the post heading would say PHP, not ImageMagick. Well, according to my logic. I am not against any heading improvement. But anyway, 2 of the 3 characters shortening since the first version are on shell side. :)

Answer (score 4):

## R, <strike>124</strike>, <strike>122</strike>, 111

```
frame()
p=polygon
p(c(1,3,5)/5,c(1,3,1)/5,c=4)
p(c(2,4,3)/5,c(2,2,1)/5,c="white")
symbols(.6,.4,.1,i=1,a=T,f=3)
```

This produces the following picture in a plot window:

[image]

Comment: I think you can save one character by writing `p=polygon`, then `p(c(1,3,5` etc. (BTW, on my system, the circle size  scales differently than the triangles when the window is resized, and I have to play with it a bit to get the circle to intersect the corners of the "square".)

Comment: @r.e.s. Thanks for the tip. The size of the circle is the major drawback of this solution. I wasn't able to figure out a short code to solve this problem.

Comment: @plannapus Great idea, thanks! This saved 11 characters.

Answer (score 3):

### Java, <strike>434</strike> <strike>358</strike> 349

```
import java.awt.*;
public class T
{
    public static void main(String[] a)
    {
        new Frame()
        {
            public void paint(Graphics g)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                Polygon p=new Polygon(new int[]{50, 75, 100},new int[]{75, 50, 75},3);
                g.fillPolygon(p);
                p.translate(-25, 25);
                g.fillPolygon(p);
                p.translate(50, 0);
                g.fillPolygon(p);
                g.setColor(Color.green);
                g.drawOval(50, 50, 50, 50);
            }
        }.show();
    }
}
```

golfed

```
import java.awt.*;public class T{public static void main(String[] a){new Frame(){public void paint(Graphics g){g.setColor(Color.BLUE);Polygon p=new Polygon(new int[]{50,75,100},new int[]{75,50,75},3);g.fillPolygon(p);p.translate(-25,25);g.fillPolygon(p);p.translate(50,0);g.fillPolygon(p);g.setColor(Color.green);g.drawOval(50,50,50,50);}}.show();}}
```

Who knew golfing reduces code so much.

EDIT: Thanks manatwork for all your suggestions.

Comment: Please golf your code.

Comment: You still have useless spaces after parameter separator commas. And please use code block instead of inline code markup, so scripts like [Code Golf UserScript Enhancement Pack](http://stackapps.com/questions/2048/code-golf-userscript-enhancement-pack) can recognize it as code  and displays its size.

Answer (score 3):

### Game Maker Language, <strike>167</strike> <strike>165</strike> 155

EDIT 1 - I shaved off two characters by replacing `c_green` with `32768`, the same value. The other color's values were longer than their predefined names.

EDIT 2 - Epic golf! Used variables for frequently used values, and forgot that newlines aren't needed (newlines count as two spaces).

The room (`r`) is predefined 64 by 32 with a white background. Object `d` is anywhere in room `r`. Draw Event code:

```
a=16b=32draw_set_color(c_blue)draw_triangle(0,b,64,b,b,0,0)draw_set_color(32768)draw_circle(b,a,a,1)draw_set_color(c_white)draw_triangle(a,a,48,a,b,b,0)
```

Result:

[image: Output of room r]

### Ti84-Basic - 54 characters (but output is black and white)

```
:Line(0,0,2,0
:Line(0,0,1,1
:Line(2,0,1,1
:Circle(1,.5,.5
```

Comment: No pictures used!

Comment: Does the figure appear in its own window?

Comment: @DavidCarraher Yes. I used in-game screen capture, so the window doesn't show up.

Comment: You used `draw_set_color` three times. Can't you save characters by something like `d=draw_set_character`?

Comment: @DavidCarraher I tried that already; it doesn't work :( GML gets kind of stubborn sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

### HTML, 101

```
<img style=position:absolute;clip:rect(30px,130px,110px,20px) src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE6m9.png>
```

Comment: There's a new requirement - "No stealing images by providing links."

Comment: I bet you could beat that with a simple:  `http://someshort.url` (... and that this would create another requirement as well)

Answer (score 2):

### HTML+CSS, <s>352</s> <s>290</s> <s>261</s> 257

```
<div style="width:0;border:50px solid #fff;border-bottom-color:#00f">
<p style="border:25px solid #00f;border-top-color:#fff;border-bottom:0;margin:25px 0 0 -25px">
<p style="border:1px solid #0f0;border-radius:50px;width:50px;height:50px;margin:-52px -26px">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WF3hP/6/

Ungolfed:

```
<style>
    #blue-triangle {
        width:0;
        border:50px solid #fff;
        border-bottom-color:#00f
    }
    #white-triangle {
       border:25px solid #00f;
       border-top-color:#fff;
       border-bottom:0;
       margin:25px 0 0 -25px        
    }
    #circle {
       border:1px solid #0f0;
       border-radius:50px;
       width:50px;
       height:50px;
       margin:-52px -26px        
     }
</style>
<div id="blue-triangle">
<p id="white-triangle">
<p id="circle">
```

Comment: Instead of setting `border-left` and `border-right` separately, better set `border` then reduce the unneeded one like `border-top:0`: http://jsfiddle.net/WF3hP/2/

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend that too. It will make your code shorter.

Comment: @manatwork, even that can be improved with `border-bottom-color` instead of `border-bottom` on the first div and similarly `border-top-color` on the second div. And using `1em` instead of `25px` and `2em` instead of `50px` changes the size but saves a few characters.

Comment: Thanks, @manatwork & Pete Taylor. I tried using em instead of px, but it's hard to get the circle centred if its border has to be 1px wide.

Comment: Do the id's really have to be that long?

Comment: The id's are only in the ungolfed version, for clarity. In the golfed version, I'm using inline styles.

Answer (score 2):

### R, 108 characters

Very similar to [Sven Hohenstein solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15521/6741) but differs in two interesting points, so I thought I would add it:

```
frame()
p=polygon
p(c(0:3,1:4)/5,c(0:1,0:1,1:2,1:0)/5,c=4)
t=seq(0,2*pi,.1)
p(.2*cos(t)+.4,.2*sin(t)+.2,b=3)
```

Instead of drawing a large blue triangle and a small white one, I draw a polygon representing already the three triangles. As for the circle, this one (whose code is clearly longer than Sven's) doesn't lose its contacts with the triangles on resize.
Finally instead of using the color names I used their number in R's default color palette (4 for blue and 3 for green).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### JavaScript (canvas, Firefox), <s>237</s> 231 characters

```
<body onload=with(c=document.all.a.getContext('2d'))fillStyle='#00F',strokeStyle='#0F0',mozFillRule='evenodd',c.f=lineTo,moveTo(4,0),f(8,4),f(0,4),f(2,2),f(6,2),f(4,4),f(2,2),fill(),beginPath(),arc(4,2,2,0,7),stroke()><canvas id=a>
```

I couldn't find any hard requirements on the dimensions, so I decided to abuse that a bit and go with 8×4 pixels to cut down code size... also, relies on the Mozilla extension mozFillRule to get even-odd filling for the triforce.

[jsbin (small)](http://jsbin.com/onUfAYA/4/watch), [jsbin (bigger)](http://jsbin.com/onUfAYA/3/watch)

Answer (score 1):

#### SVG <s>305</s> 296

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="1 3 9 10">
<path d="M 5,4 2.5,7 7.5,7 5,4 z M 7.5,7 5,10 10,10 7.5,7 z M 5,10 2.5,7 0,10 5,10 z"
fill="#00f" /><path d="m 7.5,7 a 2.5,3 0 0 1 -5,0 2.5,3 0 1 1 5,0 z"
fill="none" stroke="#0f0" stroke-width="0.02" /></svg>
```

[image: Firefox window with svg draw]

Comment: Instead of `style="fill:#00f"`, you can use `fill="#00f"`, I think. Same for the other `style`s.

Comment: @minitech: I must be able to save 5 more bytes in shifting this drawing up by `1`: having vertical plan from `2 to 9` instead of `3 to 10`...

Answer (score 1):

### Sage (CLI), <s>111</s> 106

```
p=polygon;circle((2,1),1,color=(0,1,0))+p([(0,0),(2,2),(4,0)])+p([(1,1),(3,1),(2,0)],axes=0,color=(1,1,1))
```

[image: image in window created by Sage] This is via the Sage command line interface. (This works also in a Sage Notebook, but although the image appears in its own cell, that probably doesn't qualify as a "window".)

EDIT: Eliminated 5 minus signs and replaced the screenshot of a Sage Notebook cell with one of a Sage CLI window. (Credit @boothby)

Comment: If you call `.show()` on a graphics object from the CLI, it will pop up a window.  Also you can save a few characters by shifting everything (+2,+1).

Comment: @boothby - Thanks for the idea to get rid of the minus signs. About the window, it turns out that running the program as-is (without .show()) produces the desired window from the Sage CLI. (Neither this nor the .show() version works when I run Sage under Linux in a virtual machine (Win7/VirtualBox). Works fine when I boot up Ubuntu and run Sage that way.) Thanks for the nudge to try the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

## HTML 118

```
<svg><path fill=#00f d="M0,2 2,0 4,2 2,2 3,1 1,1 2,2z"/><circle fill=none stroke-width=.1 stroke=#0f0 cx=2 cy=1 r=1 />
```

Answer (score 0):

### Golf-Basic 84, 36 characters (Output is Black and White)

```
l;0,0,2,0l;0,0,1,1l;2,0,1,1c;1,.5,.5
```